# Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port

Tags: npm, angular-cli

When trying to run `ng serve` I get the following error:

```
Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! product@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the product@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mohammad Ajo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-18T18_19_41_366Z-debug.log
```

I've checked the port if it's reserved by another connection or not and tried to change the port multiple times with not and keep getting the same error.

Comment: close vscode and reopen it, 10$ you're running more than one terminal

Comment: `lsof -i :4200` to find it and kill it ( Liam Neeson style )

Comment: I'm using intelliJ on Windows 10. The error still appears even after restarting my computer.

Comment: Go to resource montior(you can search it in start menu), and open the `network` tab, and check which process is using the 4200 port and `end process` it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue just a couple of hours ago. Try checking out:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15369

Installing portfinder@1.0.21 worked in my case.

Comment: Thank you Very much. The issue has been fixed after adding "portfinder": "1.0.20" to my package.json.

Answer (score 3):

For Linux users:-
this one is working for me

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:4200)
```

Answer (score 1):

to connect asp.net web api project with angular I have given port 4200 to it.If you just not did like that you can use ng serve --port 4600 like another port it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `ng serve --port 4500` or change `package.json` and instead of

`"start": "ng serve",`

type

`"start": "ng serve --port 4500",`

and then run `npm start` command

Comment: I've tried that multiple times but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Run following command, `---o` will open new window automatically with different port :

```
ng serve ---o --port=0 // will open on random port automatically
```

If you want specific port then run :

```
ng serve ---o --port 4201 // Will open on port 4201
```